# Inheritance : using base class or derived class to do stuff

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, language-agnostic

This is a simple question about the way inheritance should be used.

Consider that I have to provide business logic to print 'foo' and 'bar' and I have hierarchy of two classes: one that has method to print only 'foo' and another that extends first and has method to print 'bar'. 
In both classes, I have a method named as `necessaryMethod()` that takes responsibility to call those methods that prints 'foo' and 'bar'.

The way I implemented it in two approaches:

First approach is let base class do some stuff and derived class take advantage of it. The second approach is let base class not do any stuff (only providing implementation) and put all responsibility over derived class.

Consider the following code:

**Approach 1:**

```
public class A{

    protected void necessaryMethod(){
        callFoo();
    }

    protected void callFoo(){
        System.out.pritln("foo");
    }       
}

public class B extends A{

    @Override
    protected void necessaryMethod(){
        super.necessaryMethod();
        callBar();
    }

    protected void callBar(){
        System.out.println("bar");
    }   
}

public class FooBarClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        B b = new B();
        b.necessaryMethod();
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
public abstract class A{

    protected abstract void necessaryMethod();

    protected void callFoo(){
        System.out.pritln("foo");
    }       
}

public class B extends A{

    @Override
    protected void necessaryMethod(){
        calFoo();
        callBar();
    }

    protected void callBar(){
        System.out.println("bar");
    }   
}

public class FooBarClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        B b = new B();
        b.necessaryMethod();
    }
}
```

Which approach would be nice for maintainability of and readability of code (in the context of large software products/ big class hierarchy; this is just an example)?

(This is a general programming question. I did not ask for opinions.)

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @jaco0646 How to migrate the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving away from the technical aspect of programming for a moment, how something behaves (its methods) helps to define it. i.e. A dog barks().

The general question is:

1. Does the behaviour callFoo() make you think of an 'A' (class A), or a 'B'?

1.1. organise methods (behaviours) in the classes that they would belong to outside of programming - in defining the class.

**Large Code Bases**

Even though B's might belong to the set of A's in the real world, sometimes too much inheritance can work against navigating and maintaining code. The purpose of inheritance is more important and implementing inheritance itself and calls not to use inheritance may be better.

I implemented a large code base a year ago, quite proud of the complex UML behind it, however revisiting it recently was a nightmare. in some places I could have use more discretion with choosing to employ inheritance or not.

The question in this context is: Does this inheritance help to organise the code? would it help another programmer?

**Abstract Classes**

Does it make sense to instantiate an instance of the super class at any point in your program, in place of one of it's sub classes? If not, then the Abstract super class gets a vote.

Comment: +1 for talking about responsibilities and not technical constraints of the implementation. A reference to GRASP might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use derived classes but mask them as base classes, the base class should have every functionality of the derived class (because you tell the object to "think" it is A and forget it is B). So in my opinion best approach is:

```
public abstract class A{
   protected abstract void callBar();
   protected abstract void callFooBar();
   protected void callFoo() {
      System.out.pritln("foo");
   }
}

public class B extends A {
@Override
  protected void callBar(){
    System.out.println("bar")
  }
@Override
  protected void callFooBar(){
   callFoo();
   callBar();
  }
}
```

And then call B as A like this:

```
A b = new B();
b.callFooBar();
```

I think this is quite maintainable, because once you create the base class, you are pretty flexible with what you can do with derived classes and you are always just one step ahead with your derived class compared to base class. Unless you dabble into overinheritance, which is always bad. Always try to have only 1-level inheritance, occassionaly two. Anything else spirals out of control quickly, and if you need that many inheritances, it may be good idea to evaluate if interfaces are not better option.